# Remove stuck tailpipe from sink

Tags: kitchens, pipe, sink

I want to replace my kitchen strainer and to do this, I'm trying to replace the tailpipe - but it's stuck. I was able to unscrew the nut all the way I believe. If you look at the picture below, you can see a little pvc on the tailpipe showing...I'm not sure what is still holding onto it.

Any advice? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the white PVC pipe from the strainer by removing the brass nut and pulling down on the white pipe. Once that PVC is removed you need to remove the metal nut which is shown just above the brass nut in the picture.  This will allow you to remove the sink's strainer. Good luck